# What different sensing approaches are used in the current batch of indoor 3D cameras?

Tags: sensors, kinect, cameras, lidar

I'm aware of the PrimeSense camera powering the Kinect. Are more advanced sensor types available now in the < $500 range? For example, has there been any sort of game-changer in structured light techniques? Do decent flash lidar cameras exist now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the approach in structured cameras is pretty much the same.

However, the world is trying to minify this kind of sensors.
In particular

- http://structure.io/
- https://www.google.com/atap/projecttango/

Some people speculate that the reason for kinect to be so big is the array of microphones that allows to localize source of noise.

I haven't heard of anything else, though if I find new info I will expand my answer.